# Do I have to include the static class in order to use it

Tags: php

I'm somewhat new to PHP. I wrote static class that I would like to use and call, however when I try to call it I get a fatal because the php class file is not in the same directory as the calling file. Do I have to include it in order to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use `include` to include other PHP files. Even if your class file in the same directory, you still need to include it (you can also include files from other directories, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Any code that is in another file must be included. You can avoid explicitly loading the class in that page by using `require()` if you use an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php).

Comment: note that `include` (and `require`) are _statements_, not functions. i always use e.g. `include 'filename.php';` to avoid any possible confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The class must be loaded to use it.  This is true for instantiting it or calling a static function.  Use require, require_once, include, or include_once to load the class file.